# create mouse down event handller in run time

Tags: c#

I write a win app,and in run time i make many controls and locate on my forms,now i want to handell the mouse down event for any control that i create,now how can i do it??it's important for me that when the mouse down event occerred ,i understand from which control is occurred.
my controls that i create are picture box.
my question is clear??
thanks.

Comment: No, your question is not clear.  WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `control.MouseDown += SomeMethod;` and check the `sender` parameter in `void SomeMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { ... }`.

Comment: @na.farzane  this is your best bet

Comment: how can check the sender that it from one control??

Comment: i should write this event handeller for all controls that are created??

Comment: @naf: You can add the same handler to many controls and check the `sender` parameter to figure out which control fired the event.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a selection handler class and then require each of your controls to implement it. SLaks idea sounds good for something not too complex, but as you add more controls to your page a selection handler will be more efficient from both a code maintenance and code execution standpoint.